# Yii dependent dropDownMenu with variable update target

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I'm using standard `Yii` dependent `dropDownMenu` (something similar to [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/24/)). The logic is that current dropDown will define which element (next dropDown) will be updated with controller action.

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('level_1', '', $arrayWithValues, aaray(
  'ajax'=>array(
    'type'=>'POST',
    'url'=>Ccontroller::createUrl('myActionName'),
    'update'=>'#level_2'
)));
```

My question is how can I change the update value after the action is executed? i.e the action find out that we need to populate DropDown `Level_3` instead of `Level_2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('level_1', '', $arrayWithValues, aaray(
  'ajax'=>array(
    'type'=>'POST',
    'dataType' => 'json',
    'data'=>array('selected'=>'js:this.value'),,
    'url'=>Ccontroller::createUrl('myActionName'),
    'success'=>'js:function(data){
       if (data.update==2){
          $("#level_2").empty(); 
          $("#level_2").append(data.items);
       }
       if (data.update==3){
          $("#level_3").empty(); 
          $("#level_3").append(data.items);
       }
    }'
)));
```

In your controller you'll have selected value as $_POST['selected'].

```
public function actionmyaActionName()
{
    ....
    do what you need here
    $items.=CHtml::tag('option', array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($state),true);

    ....
    echo CJSON::encode(array(
    'update'=>$update,
    'items'=>$items
    ));
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

Form your options, define what to update.